# Make Celery use Django exception middleware

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

How do you force Celery to use a custom middleware in order to add extra debugging info and control the email account used to send error emails?

I'm using a custom Django [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) to add extra debugging info to [exceptions](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/638/) and send error emails. It works perfectly for standard Django 500 errors, but Celery appears to ignore all Django middleware. The effect is that any errors that occur in Celery only report a very limited traceback and use the default email connection, not a special connection used for reporting errors.

Comment: Can you include the contents of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` from your `settings.py` in the OP?

Answer (score 1):

Celery doesn't really have a use for django middleware but this will accomplish what I think you want.

Somewhere in your code place the following signal handler:

```python
from celery.signals import task_failure
from django.core.mail import mail_admins

from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter


@task_failure.connect
def task_failure_handler(task_id, exception, traceback, einfo, *args, **kwargs):
    exc_info = (einfo.type, exception, traceback)
    reporter = ExceptionReporter(None, *exc_info)
    debug_html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
    debug_text = reporter.get_traceback_text()

    subject = u'Exception - %s' % exception.message
    subject = subject.replace("\n", " ")[:250]

    mail_admins(subject, debug_text, html_message=debug_html)
```

In `settings.py` add the following

```
# disable default celery error emails
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `mail_admins` handler to celery logger, like so:

```
LOGGING = {

...

'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'celery': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'propagate': True (or False :) ),
    },
...
```

btw, I'm using [Sentry](https://www.getsentry.com/welcome/) for logging errors(both Django and Celery) and it's damn good!

Comment: This simply does not work.  I think what the original poster was looking for was an email notification on errors.  Not simply tracebacks.